# Displaying data from Coingecko API in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem with displaying data from API. Fetching API works well and displaying also work well, but it doesn't work when I am writing something like this: `{coin.image.thumb}`, but it works when I write something like this: `{coin.name}`. After first option I get a error like below. If someone can help me I would appreciate it so much, below is code and error.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Navbar} from '../components/index'
import axios from 'axios'

const Coin = () => {

    const params = useParams()
    const [coin, setCoin] = useState({})
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const url = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${params.coinId}`

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            setCoin(res.data)
            setLoading(true)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
      }, [])

  return (
    <div className='text-gray-700'>
        <Navbar />
        <div className='mx-auto max-w-7xl p-8'>
            <div>
                <img src={coin.image.thumb}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Coin
```

[image: Error]

I tried changing it to `setCoinImage` to fetch image directly but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Error that you attached, it's occurring because coin object has no property named image and thumb.

If you look at the coin state, if's initial value it's empty object {}.

'coin.image.thumb'

above code going to give us error like 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thumb')'
Because coin is empty object 'coin.image' will return undefined, since 'coin.image' is undefined 'coin.image.thumb' is like 'undefined.thumb'. Error message says this as well

First you need to check if the object has a property that you are going to use.
Like below examples

```
{ coin.image && coin.image.thumb && (
   <img src={coin.image.thumb}/>
)}
```

or

```
{ coin.image?.thumb && (
   <img src={coin.image.thumb}/>
)}
```

```
<img src={coin.image?.thumb}/>
```

```
<img src={coin.image && coin.image.thumb}/>
```